# JContent With Auto-playing AND Manually Sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

My client wants a content slider which auto-playing the content and if user clicks on next/prev, he can manually slide the content also.

[JContent Slider](http://do-web.com/jcontent/overview)

I've found this content slider, which is prefect for my other requirements, so I don't want another script, just asking if there's a way to modify this to enable auto-playing in manual mode?

I've tried this, but when I turn on auto-play, the prev/next button doesn't work anymore and the auto-playing goes crazy, like sliding the content really fast.
(one more thing, the circling option is also important for me)